# How to pass a prop Function in a Redirect in react

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I have a function that toggles a useState variable. I have a function that toggles the variable. In my App.js i have a Redirects to a component. I am unsure how to pass the prop
function to the component though the Redirect. The Toggle Function i want to pass is called onToggle the function that does the toggling is called whichchoice. i have tried the following to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.
======== The App.js ========

```
<Switch>
          {getRoutes(routes)}
          <Redirect from="*" to="/dashboards/default" onToggle={whichchoice} />
</Switch>
```

======== The component dashboard/default =======

```
};
function Default(onToggle) {

return (
  <SuiBox mt={4} mb={1}>
            <SuiButton
              variant="gradient"
              color="info"
              size="large"
              fullWidth
              onClick={() => {
                onToggle();
              }}
            >
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <Redirect from="*" to={{
        pathname: "/dashboards/default",
        state: { onToggle: whichchoice }
      }}/>
```

then in your default Component you access it:

```
console.log("onToggle",this.props.location.state.onToggle);}
```

Comment: You are the man Thank you so much

Comment: I am having an issue, How do i assign the this this.props.location.state.onToggle to the onClick button